# What is the right way to avoid antecedent ambiguity?

Tags: ambiguity, antecedents

I want to convey the idea that the actor worked in Quentin Tarantino's films in his early days --> early days of the actor, not Tarantino.
Which version is correct?

1. He worked in three other films by Quentin Tarantino in his early days. --> This may read like I am talking about Tarantino's early days, not the actor's.
2. He worked in three other films by Quentin Tarantino, in his early days. --> Does using the  comma after Tarantino clarify that I am talking about the actor's early days, not QT's?

I understand I can solve this confusion by writing it like this: "In his early days, he worked in three other films by Quentin Tarantino." But, I want to know if there's a grammatical solution in the initial versions of the statements.

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure the comma provides the definitive clarification you're looking for. The solution you suggest solves the problem; why is it unacceptable?

Comment: @gorlux Yes, the solution works, but I was curious if there is a way to solve the ambiguity in the first format.

Comment: @deltavin - Welcome to the community.

Comment: @deltavin - The comma does not remove the ambiguity and is not a good way of punctuating your sentence.  Below I have proposed an alternative that avoids punctuation errors and also removes the ambiguity.

Comment: @StuartF Sounds like an answer, no?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend your proposed third alternative, punctuated as follows.

> In his early days he worked in three other films by Quentin Tarantino.

This is a substantial improvement to the sentence, because the time period (his early days) is immediately adjacent to the verb (worked).  As a result, there is no longer any ambiguity.

I do not see any version of your first two alternatives that would avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

The ambiguity comes from antecedent-matching. Both “He” and “Quentin Tarantino” qualify as the antecedent to “his”. Proximity tends to push first impressions away from your intended “He-his” match.

The comma doesn’t really help resolve the ambiguity. What it does is add emphasis to the timing - they worked together in the *early* films rather than *later* ones.

To resolve the ambiguity, you can reword as you suggest, so that “he” is closer to “his”. The alternative is to change the pronoun to something more specific, but this is problematic here because the antecedent is another pronoun.